# Limit of two real variables function $f(x,y)=|x|^{1/|y|}$ at the origin

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Any help in computing the limit of the function $|x|^{(1/|y|)}$ at the origin will be appreciated.

Comment: When $0<y<1$ we have $1/y>1$  So if $0<x<1$ we have $x^{1/y} < x$.  Is that enough?  Also: is $|x|^{1/|y|}$  defined on the $x$-axis?

Comment: It's OK, Dear GEdgar

Answer (score 1):

Assume $x>0$, $y>0$, then
$$
x^{1/y} = e^{(\ln x)\cdot(1/y)}.
$$
As $x\to 0$ and $y\to 0$, we have
$$
\ln x\to-\infty, \quad 1/y\to + \infty,
$$
therefore,
$$
(\ln x)\cdot(1/y)\to-\infty,
$$
which implies that
$$
x^{1/y} = e^{(\ln x)\cdot(1/y)} \to 0.
$$